# how to change color of vaadin grid inline borders

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I want to change inline borders color.

Basically this is my grid

```
    grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    docID = grid.addColumn("docID").setHeader("ID").setAutoWidth(true);
    subquery = grid.addColumn("subquery").setHeader("Aranan Metin").setAutoWidth(true);
    name = grid.addColumn("name").setHeader("Bulunan Metin").setAutoWidth(true);
    similarity = grid.addColumn("similarity").setHeader("Benzerlik Oranı").setAutoWidth(true);
    grid.setDataProvider(new ListDataProvider<> 
           (searchResultLogRepository.findBySearchId(Integer.parseInt(searchID))));
```

And  this is what I am doing

```
grid.getStyle().set("border","1px solid black");
```

The result is [image]

But what I actually want is

[image]

I don't have that much css knowledge. How can I change the color and boldness of inline borders.

Comment: 1px solid red,  you can use primary colors with no problems, (red,blue,green,black,orange,purple...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add class name generator

```
grid.setClassNameGenerator(item -> "my-border");
```

And then create css file, "frontend/styles/grid-styles.css", which contains

```
.my-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

And add this annotation to main layout or view where you have the Grid

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/grid-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
```

Comment: thank you for your response it solves mostly but still, I have a problem. The header part of grid borders is not affected by the solution u share. ( https://ibb.co/6JssXnq ) here is the link for screenshot of grid

Answer (score 0):

Add style name to your grid component:

```
grid.addStyleName("grid-table-column-seperators")
```

Then add css style for class `.grid-table-column-seperators` which looks like this :

```
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: This could work with Vaadin 8, but not Vaadin 14, as the component implementation is protected in shadow DOM.